# Ajax jquery transition height on list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to do a dynamic list with some items loaded with ajax.

I have my list of items, and I would like to show & hide just one of them with a height transition. I don't know how to clean my list. I try .empty() from jQuery but it didn't work.

See here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFVYn.jpg

An exemple of my code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGJQgk

```
// load list items
$.getJSON(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
    function(data) {
        // list of items
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            $('.items').append('<div class="item" id="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + ' <br>Click me</div>');
        }
    }
);

// load item on click
$('.items').on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    // id of the selected item
    var id = $(this).attr('id') - 1;
    // height of the item box - can be different with mobile devive
    var heightOfItem = $(this).height();
    $('.background').css({
        'height': '' + heightOfItem + ''
    });

    // insert selected item
    $.getJSON(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        function(data) {
            $('.showClickedItem').append('<div class="item" id="' + data[id].id + '">' + data[id].name + '</div>')
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: You do not have to empty the list. Use `html` in place of `append` this will clear the output everytime you are changing it.

Comment: yeah Franco, but what about the height transition ?

Comment: I would use an other approach. Keep in mind that if your list become more large, the user has to scroll up in order to see the result which you are placing on the list top. A  more intuitive approach is to place the result just under the link that is clicked. Maybe you could use an accordion for this.

Comment: Do you want this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgXZrr

Comment: I know Franco, i use scrollTo, to show items, it's not the best way but i like it.

Comment: Waldermarlce yeah it's a good option to use slideUp and down, but my problem is still here because the height doesn't change.